# Connect ssms 2012 using Windows authentication

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012-express

How to connect ssms using Windows authentication. Do we need to create new servername using connection string? I saw different pages which haven't help me..

Answer (score 1):

You just open SSMS an choose Windows authentication. If I understand you correctly.

See picture 
[image]

Comment: what should be the servername

Comment: Server name should be IP of machine or Name of machine.
Format: `<servername>[\<instancename>]`.
By default instance name will be `MSSQLSERVER`